# SQL change value in varchar2 datatype using SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a problem here.
in my database i've value in `mobile_phone` column like `628932323` but i wanna change every row which use `62 to 0`

```
old value : 628932323
new value : 08932323
```

can someone help me to solve my problems. thanks

Comment: do you need to replace *starting* 62s in every number, or do you need to replace *every* 62s in every number?

Comment: so, first occurence or each occurence? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using oracle 10g or higher, you can use the regexp_replace function http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

```
select regexp_replace(your_column, '62([:digit:]*)', '0\2')
from your_table;
```

Or a more old-fashioned way without:

```
select case
         when your_column like '62%' then '0' || substr(your_column, 3)
       else
         your_column
       end
from your_table;
```

Just be careful with leading spaces or other characters in your phone number strings.